# Filter values within a group, but return all values (records) for all other groups

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have my data in this format. I would like to use dplyr to select values from Group 'b' greater than 5, but select all values from all other groups

```
Group   Value
a   3
a   4
a   8
a   3
b   3
b   8
b   7
b   9
c   2
c   3
c   9
c   8
```

so final table should look like this:

```
Group   Value
a   3
a   4
a   8
a   3
b   3
c   2
c   3
c   9
c   8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a logical condition in `filter` to get all rows where 'Group' is 'b' and 'Value' greater than 5 and negate (`!`) it

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(!(Group == "b" & Value > 5))
#   Group Value
#1     a     3
#2     a     4
#3     a     8
#4     a     3
#5     b     3
#6     c     2
#7     c     3
#8     c     9
#9     c     8
```